# Probability of selecting an even number from the set of natural numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In the above problem, if I form the sample space as the following set:
$$S= \{\text{even number, odd number}\}.$$
Obviously both events are equally likely, since there is no reason to prefer one over the other. Also, this is the set of all possible outcomes of the experiment in which a number is being randomly selected from the set of natural numbers (note that an experiment can have more than one sample spaces). So why is $P(\text{selecting an even number})$ not as simple as
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{\text{number of favourable outcomes from the sample space}}{\text{total outcomes in sample space}}?$$

Comment: Because you can't randomly select a natural number in such a way that each number has an equal probability. If you think about it a little, you will see why.

Comment: $\{1,3,2,5,7,4,9,11,6,13,15,8,17,19,10,21,23,12,\dots\}$  I can write all natural numbers in a list and that list *looks* like odd numbers happen a lot more than even numbers.  Sure, the numbers aren't written in order, but why should that matter?  (*Clearly you want the answer to be $\frac{1}{2}$ and there are plenty of concepts which give that result.  I'm just trying to point out how some naive arguments can fail depending on how such a set in question is written*)

Answer (score 10):

There is no uniform distribution on a countably infinite set, so you can't define a probability like this just by counting.

There are a couple of ways people get around this.  The most natural is to introduce a cutoff $N$ and then pass to the limit as $N\to \infty$.  Thus, for each natural number $N$, we can consider the integers between $-N$ and $N$.  Of course we can count those and we can define $P_N$ to be the probability that a (uniformly) randomly selected integer in this interval is even.  We can then define $P=\lim_{N\to \infty}P_N$.  It's not difficult to see that this implies $P=\frac 12$, as you would expect.  See [Natural Density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density).

Another method is to consider the sums of the reciprocals of the integers you are trying to "count" (taking care to remove $0$ from the list).  This is more technical and a lot less intuitive but it has some analytic properties that sometimes make it easier to work with.  This method comes up when considering subsets of the primes (see [Analytic Density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density)).  It gives $\frac 12$ in this case as well.  As you suggest, any "natural" method for computing this probability really ought to yield $\frac 12$ by symmetry.

Comment: “There is no uniform distribution on an infinite set” — surely you mean on a *countable* infinite set. There most definitely is an uniform distribution on the infinite set $[0,1]$.

Comment: @celtschk  Yes, thank you.  I'll edit accordingly.